# Grover's algorithm: Rotation in opposite direction

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, grovers-algorithm

In Grover's algorithm we have the solution superposition $|\omega\rangle$ and the non-solution superposition $|s'\rangle$ (containing all non-solutions). Furthermore, we rotate our starting equal-superposition state $|s\rangle$ (where all states have equal probability) towards $|\omega\rangle$ during the algorithm.

It is clear that in a typical scenario, the number of solutions is a lot smaller than the number of elements and therefore $|s\rangle$ is a lot 'closer' to $|s'\rangle$ than to $|\omega\rangle$ (i.e. $\langle s |s' \rangle \gg \langle s | \omega \rangle$).

---

So the question is: is there no way we can rotate towards $|s' \rangle$ instead of rotating towards $| \omega \rangle $, as this would take a lot fewer steps?

---

Obviously, knowing the non-solutions is equivalent to knowing the solutions themselves.

Even though the search algorithm is already optimal (i.e. such a circuit cannot exist probably), it is not clear at all to me why we cannot construct a circuit that does this opposite rotation. Is there some intuition behind that?

[image: 1]

Image from [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm#/media/File:Grovers_algorithm_geometry.png))

Comment: As you alluded to, the optimality of Grover implies that the algorithm must make at least $\Omega(\sqrt{2^n})$ steps or "rotations", so you simply can't expect to be able to do less. You also said that knowing non-solutions is the same as finding solutions, so if you could rotate in fewer steps in the "other direction" then you would be contradicting optimality.

Answer (score 3):

Well, technically, this works, but the complexity is worse than what you think. The problem is this sentence:

> Obviously, knowing the non-solutions is equivalent to knowing the solutions themselves.

That's true, but knowing the non-solutions entirely is hard. Let us assume that I'm looking for an $n$-bit element $w$ amongst all possible $n$-bit strings (for instance, a cipher's key).

Rotating "the other way" is simple : it takes $\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}\right)=\mathcal{O}(1)$ steps to get an answer $s$ which we know isn't a solution to our problem. We then continue until we've completely determined the set of non-solutions, which takes $O\left(2^n\right)$ operation, since the aforementioned set has $2^n-1$ elements.

On the other hand, running Grover towards the solution runs in $\mathcal{O}\left(2^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)$.

More generally, as @Condo mentioned in the comments, Grover's algorithm is exactly optimal **for the problem it solves**. That is, unless you have more assumptions about your problem, it is not possible to find an algorithm that will do better than Grover's.